# Second derivative test for discriminant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: Find all critical points of $f(x,y)=x^3+y^4-6x-2y^2$

Apply 2nd Derivative test to each point and determine whether it is local maximum, local minimum or saddle point or that the test fails.

I have found six critical points in total and applying the discriminant equation for 2 variables [ discriminant= (fxx)(fyy) - (fxy)^2 , which is 24x(3y^2 -1) in this question ] , what should be my next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that for $f(x,y)=x^3+y^4-6x-2y^2$

- $f_x=3x^2-6=0 \implies x=\pm \sqrt 2$
- $f_y=4y^3-4y=0 \implies y=0 \,\lor\,y=\pm 1$

then evaluate

- $f_{xx}=6x$
- $f_{xy}=f_{yx}=0$
- $f_{yy}=12y^2-4$

at each critical point and consider the Hessian determinant at each point.

Refer to

- [**Second partial derivative test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test)

Comment: x should be equal to +/- root2?

Comment: @CCola Opsss yes of course...I fix the typo!